# PHP - mysqli connection fails for one of ways

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to php and I don't quite understand one thing.

My file `host.php` imports config and returns new instance of `mysqli()`.
In another `php` file, when I try creating new connection:

```
try {
    $connection1 = require_once 'host.php';

    $config = require_once 'config.php';
    $connection2 = new mysqli($config['host'], $config['user'], $config['password'], $config['database']);
}
```

And when I dump it

```
var_dump($connection1);
var_dump($connection2);
```

I got on my screen

```
bool(true)
```

And

```
object(mysqli)
```

`host.php` file contains exactly the same lines as written above with `$config = ...` but instead of `$connection2` it returns `new mysqli(...)` object.
Why do those two instances returns other values after initialising?
Thank you for helping me understand it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `return` to return a value from the included file. Otherwise it will only tell you whether a file was included or not.

In one of your files create mysqli connection, taking into consideration the three steps that are needed. Do not add any try-catch or any other noise.

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

return $mysqli;
```

Then in your other file include it and assign the return variable.

```
<?php

$conn = require_once 'mysqli.php';
```

Now you can use `$conn` to execute your SQL statements.

Of course, such a thing makes very little sense unless you wrap it in an IIFE. For 3 lines of code it makes no difference. You are not polluting the global scope with variables. If you use PHP config file and you would like to keep these variables in a scope then an IIFE might make sense.

```
return (function () {
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $config = require_once 'config.php';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($config['host'], $config['user'], $config['password'], $config['database']);
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

    return $mysqli;
})();
```

Comment: So, for my better understanding, IIFE helps to not produce these variables, just only prepares them and returns without any declaration? That would make a lot of sense, because this way worked for me but when I used this `$connection = require_once` in few files, when this error happened. Your way is excelent solution and I like it a lot. Thank you for it!

Comment: IIFE is just a way of keeping variables defined in a local scope.

Comment: Yeah, that's something I was missing. That's why I had this error with returned `bool`, I had it globally. Thank you for your help and knowledge, it's a huge milestone for me while learning web development. Bless ya :)

Answer (score -2):

require cannot return. you must set $connection1 = new mysqli in your other file.

Comment: And `require` returns true because it successfully found and ran the file, and has nothing to do with the code itself.